# How to configure Application Logging Service for SCP application

Tags: s4sdk, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk

I have created the hello world application from the SAP Cloud SDK archetypes and pushed this to the cloud foundry environment, binding it to an application logging service instance. My understanding is that this should already provide me with the ability to analyze all logs in the Kibana dashboard of the cloud platform and previously it also worked this way.

However, this time the Kibana dashboard remains empty, so I am wondering if I missed a step or configuration. Looking at the documentation of the service and the respective tutorial blog, I was not able to identify any additional required steps. In the Logs view on the SCP cockpit I can definitely see the entries, but they are not replicated to the ELK stack in the background.

Comment: Hi Tim, I couldn't reproduce your issue. Using the latest released archetype, pushing it to CF and binding it to the "application-logs" service lets me see the logs in the Kibana Dashboard (after some delay of 30 secs or so). So it seems not to be an issue with the SDK itself. Therefore I would ask you to create a support ticket under component `BC-NEO-CF-APPLOG`: https://support.sap.com/en/index.html

Comment: Hi, it seems indeed that this was an issue with the SCP itself. Without changing anything it just worked sometime later today. So, thanks anyhow for having a look into this, next time I will make sure to raise a support ticket first...

Comment: Good to hear. Can you maybe add a quick answer then, so that this is no longer marked as unanswered? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was not SDK related, but seems to have been an incident on the SCP - now works correctly without any changes.